# Regex Pattern for the specific format in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string like `Test (123) Test` & needs to remove the `(123)` from the string.

Please help me to get the exact regex pattern for that replce?

```
Input : Test(123)Test
Output: Test Test
```

Thanks, Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: What have you tried so far? :) You know, if you want help from us, maybe show some effort first... More people would be willing to help if they see you just don't sit back and wait for the answer.

Comment: The issue also is you don't explain clearly what is it you need, being a programmer/engineer you should know you need to be specific. Is the string always going to have `(123)` then your answer just is `inString.Replace("(123)","");` Or is is some digits inside parenthesis, or is it exactly 3 digits? Would you expect us to answer all permutations? I hope you can understand how frustrating this can be.

Comment: I'm taking a guess he has problems with the brackets

Comment: If he did he should should have taken the time to express that in his question.

Comment: very sorry for the question i have posted. my requirement is having a string with the specific format. Say "Test (123) Test". inside () paranthesis could be a integer value. want to replace that specific format from the string. Expeting the Output should be "Test Test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... it will help you...

**Code :**

```
string input = "Test(123)Test";
string regex = "(\\(.*\\))";
string sOutput = Regex.Replace(input, regex, " ");
Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
```

**Output :**

```
Test Test
```

**Updated Code :**

```
string input = "(hi) (91) Professional Investment Services Pty Ltd (hi) (91)";
Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}.\\d+\\{1}", '(', ')'));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, string.Empty));
```

**Output :**

```
(hi) Professional Investment Services Pty Ltd (hi)
```

Comment: Thanks pandian. but it truncating all the character after the (123)

Comment: @gunaSamba : No it works perfectly for me.. Can you paste the same coding in your project and see the result...

Comment: following input "(91)Professional Investment Services Pty Ltd (91)" producing empty output

Comment: thanks pandian.. it works for me.. but i just want to replace the format only when if it contains number in it..

Comment: i got it used the following pattern:  Regex regexpattern = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}\\d+?\\{1}", '(', ')'));... thanks for your support